# PrimeFaces menuItem #{component}

Tags: jsf, primefaces, el

This is how my menu is working ATM (on JSF 2.2 and PrimeFaces 13.0.5)

```
    <p:menuitem value="My menu item" outcome="/some-view-id" 
        styleClass="#{currentView.isView('some-view-id') ? 'selected':''}" />
```

Notice i pass viewId 'manualy' to determine styleClass.

I would like to make 'generic' method, something like

```
    <p:menuitem value="My menu item" outcome="/some-view-id" 
        styleClass="#{currentView.isView(component.outcome) ? 'selected':''}" />
```

but this is not working! `#{component}` is referring to `<p:menu>` and not `<p:menuItem>` .

Using binding is working but i achieved nothing since i have to declare it for each menuItem.

```
    <p:menuitem value="My menu item" outcome="/some-view-id" 
        binding="#{myMenuItemBinding}"
        styleClass="#{currentView.isView(myMenuItemBinding.outcome) ? 'selected':''}" />
```

Any ideas? I was expecting `#{component}` to be `<p:menuItem>` ...

Edit: **Fixed** in PrimeFaces 13.0.6

Comment: Bug in renderer, they forgot to invoke pushComponentToEL/popComponentFromEL for every menu item, report to them.

Comment: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/11358

Comment: Looks like this bug has been around a long time: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/11358

Comment: woah that was swift response, thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was reported on GitHub and fixed in 13.0.6.

Issue: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/11358

PR: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/11361